# Is it possible to programmatically apply a filter to single frame via ffmpeg without specifying time base?

Tags: c, ffmpeg, video-processing

I'm trying to apply a filter to a single `AVFrame` following the example in https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/decode_filter_video.c
however it involves setting up

```c
const AVFilter *buffersrc  = avfilter_get_by_name("buffer");
...
snprintf(args, sizeof(args),
            "video_size=%dx%d:pix_fmt=%d:time_base=%d/%d:pixel_aspect=%d/%d",
...
```

After waddling through obscure errors and debugging the ffmpeg I've found that it doesn't like if I drop the `time_base` parameter however I don't know what to specify it to (I don't have access to this information at the point I'm trying to apply the filter) and it doesn't seem relevant to the filter I'm trying to use. Indeed, if I specify something random there I see no difference, however that feels like a hack and I'd like to know if there is some proper way you are supposed to set your filter up without specifying the time base/framerate?

Comment: time_base can be inverse of framerate, at the least.

Comment: Which parameters does one need to set?

Comment: @Gyan not available, as state in the question. Just AVFrames.

Comment: @Motomotes I don't understand your questions but time_base cannot be omitted otherwise you get invalid parameters error.

Comment: Please post a more complete of example of one's code.

Comment: @Motomotes it's basically the decode_filter_video.c example linked above, except the frames are not coming from the file on disk but from somewhere else. `init_filters` is more or less the same, except no `fmt_ctx` to get the `time_base`.

Comment: `args` can be null and the options can be set using AV Options API https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__avoptions.html

Comment: @Motomotes with null args `avfilter_graph_create_filter` returns invalid argument error.

Comment: "args Options to initialize the filter with. This must be a ':'-separated list of options in the 'key=value' form. May be NULL if the options have been set directly using the AVOptions API or there are no options that need to be set." https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.3/group__lavfi.html#ga0d21eb00b9f24213bd7c5775393a09fd

Comment: The other options need to be set first,
https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__avoptions.html#gad4ca968e9058b39b2da630ad0a091bdb

https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__avoptions.html#gab48669d1326f7d47ef39e5702e34abd2

Comment: @Motomotes https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavfilter/buffersrc.c#L300 default value for `time_base` is not accepted.